# Animations in OpenGL ES 1.x

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I am creating a real time game for android and so far I create the moving player using the commands glTranslatef () glRotatef () etc.

In [Google I/O 2009](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4Bk5rmIpic) it says that JNI functions (glXXX()) are inefficient.

Therefore my current methods of animation might not be the best.

I haven't come across using 'sprites' can someone tell me about that, or some other way of animation using OpenGL? Links to tutorials and/or docs will be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [AndEngine Sprite Example](http://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/SpriteExample.java), and [WiEngine Sprite Example](http://herossg.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-2d-02-with-wiengine.html) for sprite examples. Also you can use the NDK to access OpenGLES context. The NDK has much better support now than in 2009. In particular you can access to OpenGLES2.x and a few other things that are hard to do using JNI and or are not available in the Android java API, like certain sound operations, etc...

Another thing is that that presentation is highly inaccurate... please look up the 2010 version that is much better [Real Time Games Redux 2010](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-62tRHLcHk&list=PLDBFDC7D352893F7C), since it represents over a year of experience by the author.

Comment: Thanks for the link + AndEngine is really extensive! Can't wait to start cracking down on it.

Comment: @Jimmy if you're looking at AndEngine, you should also look at LibGDX.

Comment: Well if LibGDX is being considered then AirplaySDK should be also. It's a mature alternative for C++ programmers that want to deploy for Android, iPhone and other Mobile devices.